# Why does Func and Action Delegates only take 4 arguments?

Tags: c#

Why 4?  I know its in the documentation as 4, but that just seems strange.

Comment: Can you explain why you would need more than 4?

Comment: @Jon Limjap, can you explain why you would need more than 3?

Comment: I.e. for building mathematical forecasting model that unwraps functions into delegates based on the genocode provided)

Comment: I dont actually need any.  I was just curious.  Its odd to find things hard coded and limited like this in the .net framework, and I wanted to know if there was some logic behind it.  Someting more substantial than, "Any more than that and your code would smell."

Answer (score 6):

I'll go out on a limb and say it's because someone needed an Action or Func delegate somewhere in the framework with 4 arguments and no one has yet needed one with 5.  Alternatively, someone decided that any more than 4 and you ought to introduce a class to hold the values instead as @chadmyers says.

Comment: Bravo - way more likely to be a simple pragmatic choice, subject to change in the future, than any of these supposedly principled answers like "If you need more than four, you're doing it wrong".

Comment: And of course, it's easy enough to add your own Func overload if you need 17 parameters. But 4 seems like a nice compromise in covering most common use cases with the least amount of extra code added to the BCL.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact answer, but I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that if you are passing around delegates with >4 arguments, that's a code smell and you're likely doing something wrong. You should consider using the "[Introduce Parameter Object](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html)" refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

It is strange enough that people would need to consume four types of objects, encapsulate them, manipulate them, and keep track of them all in one class.

I would even posit that anywhere beyond three distinct types and your generic class is already going too far. Usually you have to take into account permutations of how your types interact with each other, e.g., 1 types is fine, 1 x 2 is fine, by 3 you have 6 ways to manipulate your types, by 4 you have 24 combinations to choose from, so you should take this complexity into account as well.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would agree with others that a function signature with 5 args might be getting a bit long.  Having said that, I have written plenty of long function signatures in my time as a developer.

You can always write your own overloaded generic delegates.  You could even place them in System (I wouldn't).

```
namespace System
{
  public delegate void Action<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, 
                                                  T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5);
  public delegate ReturnT Action<ReturnT, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>(T1 arg1, 
                                         T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4, T5 arg5);
}
```

Edit: Since I authored this post .Net 4. has arrived, and with it longer versions of these delegates.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 4.0, you get a lot more - up to [16 parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd402872.aspx).

Although using such *routinely* might be taking it a bit far in terms of readability...

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a bad development pattern to have delegates with that many arguments. 
It makes your code extremely coupled and complex.